# Jest Enzyme How to update child props

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I need to mutate React child component's prop which receives parents' function.
After updating the wrapper's function it changes but not affect to child component

```
// Component
import React from 'react';

export default class Component extends React.Component {
  clickFunction() {
    console.log("Parent's Click fn");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.clickFunction} data-test-id="button" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
// Test

import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';

const mockClickFunction = jest.fn(() => console.log('Mock Click fn'));

describe('Test Component', () => {
   it('Should mutate child prop', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
      wrapper.find('[data-test-id="button"]').simulate('click') // Parent's Click fn

      console.log(wrapper.instance().clickFunction) // [Function: bound clickFunction]

      wrapper.instance().clickFunction = mockClickFunction;
      wrapper.update();

      console.log(wrapper.instance().clickFunction) // [Function: mockConstructor]

      wrapper.find('[data-test-id="button"]').simulate('click') // Parent's Click fn but should be Mock Click fn
   })
})
```

How I can change child Component onClick function?

Comment: What are you testing exactly? That it will call two separate functions on subsequent clicks? It might be better to test the effects of the click (assuming they're different).

Comment: for component it will download image. but for test i will send dummy data. this is why i need mock this function

Comment: I found after parent state changed child component's props will be updated. wrapper.setState({someState: 'newstate'})

Comment: Try wrapper.instance().forceUpdate();

Answer (score 0):

A reference to the original `clickFunction` has been used in the render. You can't mock it by overriding it after the component is already shallow-rendered.

Try spying on `Component.prototype.clickFunction` before calling `shallow`.

E.g.

`index.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Component extends React.Component {
  clickFunction() {
    console.log("Parent's Click fn");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.clickFunction} data-test-id="button" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import Component from '.';

describe('55611882', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mockClickFunction = jest
      .spyOn(Component.prototype, 'clickFunction')
      .mockImplementation(() => console.log('Mock Click fn'));

    const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
    wrapper.find('[data-test-id="button"]').simulate('click');
    expect(mockClickFunction).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    mockClickFunction.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/55611882/index.test.jsx (13.099 s)
  55611882
    ✓ should pass (81 ms)

  console.log
    Mock Click fn

      at examples/55611882/index.test.jsx:9:41

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |      75 |      100 |      50 |      75 |                   
 index.jsx |      75 |      100 |      50 |      75 | 5                 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.416 s
```